# animating button css properties in jquerymobile

Tags: javascript, css, button, jquery-mobile, jquery-animate

I am trying to make a jquerymobile (v1.1.1) button animate, as if it is flashing.
I have gotten this far:

```
myButton = $('<div data-role="button" data-theme="reset" data-inline="true" >save</div>').appendTo(this.myNode);


setInterval(
    function(){

        myButton.animate ({

             opacity: 0.5

    }, 400, function(){

                myButton.animate ({

                     opacity:1,

            },400);
         });},1000);
```

The issue here is that :

1. Only with `data-theme="reset"` can I see some modification in the button's appearance.
2. Opacity seems to be the only property that can be modified.

Ideally, I would like to be able to animate the background-color or the color of text of the button, whatever data-theme it might have. Any suggestions?

Edit: If it's any help, the html that is generated by jquerymobile for the button is as follows:

```
<div data-role="button" data-theme="reset" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" 
 data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" 
 class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-reset">
      <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
          <span class="ui-btn-text">save</span>
      </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML that jQuery mobile generates for the button?  jQuery Mobile adds a lot of class declarations to the HTML on the fly.  It would help to see what it has generated for your button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS3 transitions (supported on most mobile browsers, http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions) to create the animation of color.

JS-

```
$(function () {

    //save current color so we can go between two colors
    var currentColor = "red";

    //set an interval
    setInterval(function () {
        var $this = $('a');

        //swap colors (background and text)
        if (currentColor === "red") {
            currentColor = "blue";
            $this.css({
                backgroundColor : "blue",
                color           : "white"
            });
        } else {
            currentColor = "red";
            $this.css({
                backgroundColor : "red",
                color           : "black"
            });
        }
    }, 2500);
});​
```

CSS-

```
.ui-page .ui-btn {
    background-image   : none;

    -webkit-transition : background-color 2s linear, color 2s linear;
    -moz-transition    : background-color 2s linear, color 2s linear;
    -ms-transition     : background-color 2s linear, color 2s linear;
    -o-transition      : background-color 2s linear, color 2s linear;
    transition         : background-color 2s linear, color 2s linear;
}​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yLuCt/

The CSS above removes the gradient background images from buttons so their flat-color backgrounds will be used (which can be animated via CSS). Then the `transition` declarations just define what type of animation to use on what property and for what duration should the animation last. I've set the animation to be slightly shorter than the interval so the element is not constantly animating.

Docs for Transitions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FCSS_transitions

Browser Support for Transitions: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and enlightening answer!